# Dealing with empty cells in tables in shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I am creating a very simple shiny app to show different tables. These tables are complex and contain important data.

Sometimes I intentionally create an empty cell. In the app, this empty cell always contains "X" as text. If there are more than one cell, it appears as "X", "X.1" , "X.2", etc.

How to make these cells appear empty?  Also, why there are dots that appear in my cells? They look bad. How do I remove them? Here is a screenshot.

[image]

```
ui <- navbarPage(
  
  "Title",
  
  navbarMenu(
    
  "Patient Characteristics",

  tabPanel("Table 1",
           DT::dataTableOutput("table4")
  )

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  output$table4 <- DT::renderDataTable(
    datatable(table4,
              options = list(scrollX = TRUE),
              escape = FALSE,
              rownames = FALSE)
  ) }
```

Comment: `data.frame`'s `check.names` argument by default is set to `TRUE` - it ensures that the names of the variables in the data frame are syntactically valid variable names and are not duplicated.